# Ruby on Rails, select and deselect all checkboxes

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have a button and when I click on it, I want all checkboxes to be selected. By clicking the second time, all checkboxes must be deselected.

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   $('#check_all').on("click", function(){ $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(); });
   </script>



<%= form_tag save_share_patients_clinicdb_grp_pats_path, method: :post do %>

<%= hidden_field_tag 'to_share_group', @to_shr_group%>
<button type="button" id="check_all" class="btw"><%="Check all/Uncheck all"%></button>

    <%@pat_ids.each do |pat_id|
    %>  
        <%= check_box_tag "to_share_patients[]", pat_id.mk1%> <%=pat_id.mk1%>
        <br/>
    <%end%>

<%= button_tag :class => "btn btn-warning", :name => 'share' do %> <%= t "share" %> <% end %> 
<%end%>
```

Something does not work here. Can you help me please?

***edit:***

```
 $('#check_all').on("click", function(){ alert("aaa"); });
```

does not alert anything

in application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.Jcrop
//= require jquery.purr
//= require jquery-fileupload
//= require best_in_place
//= require rails.validations
//= require_self
//= require_tree ./bootstrap
//= require_tree ./jquery
//= require_tree ./menu
//= require_tree ./notifications
//= require_tree ./search
//= require_tree ./sort
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

in application.html

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.min', 'jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "/assets/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
```

Comment: is the jQuery library included on your page?

Comment: @jljohnstone no, how can I include it?

Comment: Use the jquery-rails gem: https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails but it should have been included in your Rails project by default. Perhaps you removed it from your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file

Comment: gem 'jquery-rails' is in the Gemfile, //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs are in the application.js and it still does not work

Comment: Are you including your javascript in your application layout file (`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`) like so: `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`

Comment: @jljohnstone I do, it still does not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#check_all').on("click", function(){
  var cbxs = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
  cbxs.prop("checked", !cbxs.prop("checked"));
});
```

Comment: Had to add $( function() { })

Comment: `cbxs`? really? You can just spell out "checkboxes".

Comment: You just inverted all checkboxes. For the requested functionality you have to check the state of each checkbox separately like @Orchid did it

Answer (score 11):

U tried to call the "click" event on the element "check_all" before it gets loaded. Hence only the alert function doesnt work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#check_all').on("click", function(){ alert("hi") });
});
```

For selecting the checkboxes,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#check_all').on("click", function() {
     // grouping all the checkbox using the classname
     var checkboxes = $("class name for the checkbox");
     // check whether checkboxes are selected.
     if(checkboxes.prop("checked")){
        // if they are selected, unchecking all the checkbox
        checkboxes.prop("checked",false);
     } else {
        // if they are not selected, checking all the checkbox
        checkboxes.prop("checked",true);
     }
   });
});
```