# How to display a Rails dropdown menu with checkbox for each item in it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I have a selection dropdown in my Rails form as shown below:

```
<%= f.select :account_id, options_for_select(@entities.collect{ |e| [e.entity, e.entity] }, 1 ), {include_blank: '-Select-'}, { id: 'my_entity'} %>
```

Is there a way to display a dropdown which includes:

1. Checkboxes for each item in the dropdown and also
2. A checkbox to `select all` and `unselect all` the items in this dropdown?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Putting checkboxes in a dropdown is a very unusual thing to do.

If you want checkboxes, I would skip the `select` and just present a list of checkboxes.

But I would recommend using a regular HTML *multiple* select list by adding the `multiple` option. Something like this:

```
<%= f.select :account_id, 
      options_for_select(@entities.collect{ |e| 
        [e.entity, e.entity] 
      }, 1), 
      { include_blank: '-Select-' }, 
      { multiple: true, size: [@entities.size, 10].max }
      { id: 'my_entity'} 
%>
```

Comment: If you would have seen filters in Excel header columns, you would get a dropdown - if you click the dropdown, you would get a list of all unique items in the column with checkbox for each item. You would also get a checkbox that would allow you to select all items in the menu (or unselect all items). I am looking for something like that. The specifics of the control does not really matter to me. I would like to accomplish what Excel column heading filter does; and I would like to do that in my Rails form.

Comment: Ah...that sounds pretty fancy. I don't think you'll get that from Rails straight out of the box. I'd suggest pursuing that more on the Javascript side of things. Are you using a front-end framework like Vue or Bootstrap? You'll find tools there for the kind of thing  you're looking for. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976895/ruby-on-rails-select-and-deselect-all-checkboxes .

Comment: I am using JQuery. I found these 2 links which are close to what i need - https://jsfiddle.net/p1261jby/3/ and https://jsfiddle.net/p1261jby/3/ . But a dropdown with checkbox would be exactly what I need.

Comment: I wish I could help. Good luck, Biju.